# '<' is not a prefix unary operator

Tags: swift, if-statement, cgfloat

I want to make an if statement with an greater than symbol in it. When I type the code it gives me this error: ''<' is not a prefix unary operator'

This is my code:

```
 if messages.count == >75 {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
    } else if messages.count == <75 {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
    }
```

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Its `>`, `<`, `>=` and `<=` in Swift (as in many other programming languages). How did you come up with `== >75` ??

Comment: In the Swift language reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID70.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave out the `==`:

```
 if messages.count > 75 {
     navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
 } else if messages.count < 75 {
     navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
 }
```

There's more than just `==`, `>` and `<`:

- `A == B` means *A is equal to B*
- `A != B` means *A is not equal to B*
- `A > B` means *A is greater than B*
- `A < B` means *A is less than B*
- `A >= B` means *A is greater than or equal to B*
- `A <= B` means *A is less than or equal to B*

Check out the language docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID70).

Comment: Thanks for noticing! I really don't know how I didn't noticed it.